# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Tuple MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass two model to View.
 I have two models

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

and second

```
 public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLname { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }


}
```

I made a ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; } 
}
```

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        // retreive from database
        model.Teachers = new List<Teacher>() { new Teacher() };
        model.Departments = new List<Department>() { new Department() };

        return View(model);
    }
```

and a  in the view I have following

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<_167School.Models.Teacher>,IEnumerable<_167School.Models.Department>>


@foreach (var student in Model.Item2)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@student.DepartmentName</td>

    </tr>
}
@foreach (var teacher in Model.Item1)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@teacher.TeacherName</td>
        <td>@teacher.TeacherLname</td>
        <td>@teacher.DepartmentID</td>
    </tr>
}
```

and site goes on runtime and tell me that

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '_167School.ViewModels.ViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[_167School.Models.Teacher],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[_167School.Models.Department]]'.
```

I want to display two models data in one View. I tried this way.

PLEASE HELP
Thanks

Comment: You view needs to be `@model ViewModel`. Then access the model using `@foreach (var teacher in Model.Teachers) { ....}`

Comment: when i use  @Model in my view, View could not find my view model, and how can I tell the view that' I'm using aa Tuple?

Comment: Your not using a `Tuple`! Your passing typeof `ViewModel` to the view. Make sure you use the fully qualified name - `@model YourAssembly.ViewModel` or add a `@using` statement.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - can you post this as an answer since as it is now, it has been solved but still appears to remain open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passing typeof `ViewModel` to the view, but your view declares the model as `Tuple<T1, T2>`. Change the view to

```
@model YourAssembly.ViewModel
```

and then loop through the collections using

```
@foreach (var teacher in Model.Teachers)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@teacher.TeacherName</td>
    <td>@teacher.TeacherLname</td>
    <td>@teacher.DepartmentID</td>
  </tr>
}
```